# How to get the location of a point on a Canvas outside of the JFrame / JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, game-development

I am trying to add a mouse-look functionality into my game where one can click on a space, and the character will go to that space.

I have have a MouseListener that gives me the mouse's X and Y relevant to the JFrame coordinates.

This doesn't work because as the player moves in the world, the player's X and Y are not the same as the X and Y on the screen.

How can I get the X and Y  of what is drawn on the Canvas related to the X and Y of where the mouse is on the JFrame?

Comment: I "assume" (since you've provided no code for context), that you know the x/y offset of the word relative to the top/left corner of the window?  With this you can adjust the mouse x/y from the window to the world and back again

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that. I've been trying to do that offset from the player to the click point. I'll try that next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an (x,y) position in the World and another (x,y) coordinates for the Frame, just check where your current camera is viewing in the world and offset the differences.

[image]

Let the blue box be your World boundary and the black box be your Frame screen. Now having a game unit at location `x`.

In frame, the coordinates in accordance to the frame will be `(x: 200, y: 300)`.

If you want to get the world location, just add the current location of your camera in the world, i.e: `(200 + 1000, 300 + 1100)`.

Hence the World location for your Game Character will be at `(x: 1200, y: 1400)`.

To get the reverse, just reverse the process.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the X and Y of what is drawn on the Canvas related to the X and Y of where the mouse is on the JFrame?

You need to convert the point to be relative to another component.

Check out the `SwingUtilities` class. You would use the `convertPoint(...)` method to convert a point to be relative to any component you wish.

Also, don't use a Canvas class. That is used with AWT. When using Swing you should be using a JPanel for custom painting.

Comment: They're both being painted on the same component, so no. The first answer worked for me. And I disagree with the common opinion about the canvas class. I can achieve everything I want with it, with great fps. Currently I have a 256x256 tile world, with lighting effects, camera, and zoom/scaling, all still with 500+ fps. So far I see no reason to switch...

Comment: @MitchWeaver, `The first answer worked for me.` I didn't say it wouldn't work by hardcording some offset. However, that is NOT the proper way to solve the problem. You should not be hardcoding an offset. The offsets may be different on different platforms. You should be converting points as suggested above.  Your question stated you have different points of reference. Use the methods provided by the API and don't reinvent the wheel.